# GIS geometric operations in R

Tags: r, geometry, sf

I have a question question regarding geometric operations in R.
In the code below, I download spatial files on municipalities (lau_2011) and borderlines of nuts0 regions (nuts_bn).

I later change the nuts_bn to a polygon that has a radius of 100km around a border (nuts_bn1).
What I would like to learn is how to restrict the sample of municipalities (lau_2011) to the ones that are contained in the nuts_bn1 polygons?

```
require(giscoR)
require(tidyverse)
require(sf)
require(tmap)
require(magrittr)


# downloading spatial files -----------------------------------------------
lau_2011 <- gisco_get_lau(year = "2011", epsg = "4326") #cities
nuts_bn <- gisco_get_nuts(year = "2016", epsg = "4326", resolution = "01", spatialtype = "BN", nuts_level = "0") #boundaries

# only non-coastal biundaries ---------------------------------------------
nuts_bn %<>% filter(COAS_FLAG == "F")


# get distance from borders 100km -----------------------------------------

nuts_bn1 <- st_buffer(nuts_bn, dist = 100000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help. It joins the borders on a single object, creates a buffer of 100 km around it (mind the CRS, you are using EPSG 4326 that is defined in longitude/latitude, not meters, so you need to project) and performs an spatial operation to see if the LAU is contained in the buffer (since you didn't specify further I used `st_contains()`, but there are several options as contains properly, touches, intersect, etc, see https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_pred.html). Once that I have the results as a logical vector, it is just a matter of filtering the LAU dataset.

```r
require(giscoR)
require(tidyverse)
require(sf)
require(tmap)
require(magrittr)


# downloading spatial files -----------------------------------------------
lau_2011 <- gisco_get_lau(year = "2011", epsg = "4326") # cities
nuts_bn <- gisco_get_nuts(year = "2016", epsg = "4326", resolution = "01", spatialtype = "BN", nuts_level = "0") # boundaries
nuts_rg <- gisco_get_nuts(year = "2016", epsg = "4326", resolution = "01", spatialtype = "RG", nuts_level = "0") # regions



# only non-coastal biundaries ---------------------------------------------
nuts_bn %<>% filter(COAS_FLAG == "F")


# get distance from borders 100km -----------------------------------------
# You need to project to a CRS in meters, for example 3035

nuts_bn1 <- nuts_bn %>%
  st_transform(3035) %>%
  st_combine() %>%
  st_buffer(dist = 100000)

# Set lau2011 on same CRS
lau_2011_proj <- lau_2011 %>% st_transform(st_crs(nuts_bn1))

# Spatial join: I use here contains, but you may be looking for something else

includes <- st_contains(nuts_bn1, lau_2011_proj, sparse = FALSE)


# lau on the buffer
lau_2011_buff <- lau_2011_proj[includes[1, ], ]
nrow(lau_2011_buff)

tm_shape(lau_2011_buff) +
  tm_fill("red") +
  tm_shape(nuts_bn1) +
  tm_borders()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answe. I have question - when I run nrow(lau_2011_buff) it shows that that dataset contains only 9 observations. Shouldnt it be more (as the map suggests)?

Comment: That's odd , on my laptop it shows `62771`. I am using `sf 1.0.5`  and `giscoR 0.3.1` on a Windows machine.

Comment: Yes you were right, I had a small mistake there, now it shows also `62771`. Thanks for your help!